# Proxy in c# for a little bot

Tags: c#

I want to create a bot that displays a web page through a proxy taken from http://proxy-list.org/en/index.php.
I did this:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create ("http://www.google.it/");
request.GetResponse ();
```

so the page is displayed but does not pass the proxy.

Do you have any advice?

(Sorry for my english)

Comment: You don't pass the proxy so I'm not suprised

Answer (score 1):

You can find this on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.net.webproxy%28VS.80%29.aspx) by simply search for webrequest+proxy

```
 HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://google.it/");
 WebProxy a=new WebProxy(); a.Address=new Uri("http://97.107.137.97:8080"); 
 request.Proxy = a; 
 var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
 Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
 StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
 string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: I tried to do so but it is not displayed.
you can give me a small example:)

Comment: The example section of the msdn link ZombieHunter posted, shows a complete sample. So where is the problem exactly? Please let us know your exception or where you are struggling exactly.

Comment: HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.it/");
                WebProxy a=new WebProxy();
                a.Address=new Uri("http://97.107.137.97:8080");
                request.Proxy = a;
                request.GetResponse();
is it correct?

Comment: How are you doing with the snippet?

Answer (score 0):

20 seconds on checking for properties of the HttpWebRequest class leaded me to this:

HttpWebRequest.Proxy Property
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.proxy.aspx

I guess this took less time than writing the question...